# Installation menu in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: installation, graphics, screen, menu, system-installation

When I try to install Ubuntu, I am unable to view the installation menu. The only thing I can see is a black screen. Are there other methods to install Ubuntu 13.10, & is this a graphic problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue if I want to install Ubuntu on my HP Folio 13. The issue is that your brightness is turned off. Try to shine a lamp to your screen and select Live Mode, and then set the brightness up.

If this works for you, you can Install Ubuntu and add this line to your `/etc/rc.local` file

```
echo 1666 >> /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```